# Resolve may fail depending on order of RegisterInstance and RegisterType

Tags: unity-container

When using this object model:

```
interface IInterface {}

class Impl : IInterface
{
    public Impl(int blah) {}
}
```

And this test:

```
void Test1()
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterInstance(new Impl(3), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IInterface, Impl>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    Impl impl = container.Resolve<Impl>();
}
```

I get an exception:

`Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "BlahMain.Program+Impl", name = "(none)".`
`Exception occurred while: while resolving.`
`Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Int32 cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.`
`-----------------------------------------------`
`At the time of the exception, the container was:`
`Resolving BlahMain.Program+Impl,(none)`
`Resolving parameter "blah" of constructor BlahMain.Program+Impl(System.Int32 blah)`
`Resolving System.Int32,(none)`

It looks like Unity is trying to construct its own Impl instance, even though I have already registered one.

Changing the registration order as follows:

```
void Test2()
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    // Note: RegisterInstance is now called after RegisterType.
    container.RegisterType<IInterface, Impl>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterInstance(new Impl(3), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    Impl impl = container.Resolve<Impl>();
}
```

solves the issue.

Now, changing the order of registrations is an acceptable workaround, but it forces me to think when setting up the container. I was hoping that when using Unity I wouldn't have to worry about registration order.

Can anyone explain this behavior? Is this such a delicate use-case that I have to be aware of registration order?

---

Damian,

This is what I'm trying to do and I'm getting the same error. Is this not what you meant?

```
void Test3()
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    var impl = new Impl(3);
    container.RegisterInstance(impl, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterInstance<IInterface>(impl, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IInterface, Impl>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    var resolvedImpl = container.Resolve<Impl>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
 container.RegisterInstance<IInterface>(new Impl(3), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to call `container.Resolve<Impl>()`, no?

Comment: Please see my other answer. I'm not sure I'm following you.

Comment: This should be enough:
container.RegisterInstance(impl);
    container.RegisterInstance<IInterface>(impl);

Comment: Indeed, this works. Moreover, adding container.RegisterType<IInterface, Impl>() actually _breaks_ this.

Comment: Sorry for reviving, but could anyone explain why this extra line of code is necessary?