# Dependency Injection: Where should I inject? Who should control it?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Disclaimer: Code written without a compiler, you should discard any syntax errors. :)

I am wondering about what I am doing is "right".

Currently, I have a Manager class with static methods. Those methods each call a method on my Repository class (eg. Manager.Get will call Repository.Get, and so on).

*The Repository implementation will be injected!*

Manager has a static field that references a singleton instance to itself, as well as a reference to an instance of the repository.

```
static Manager _me = new Manager();

[Dependency]
public IRepository Repo;
```

**Note: This is how I currently do the resolving! I need feedback on this!**

In the managers Ctor, I resolve the dependency

```
public Manager()
{
    // Feedback would be nice on this as well!
    // I have a singleton reference to the container,
    // being set from the startup project.
    Repo = Singleton.UnityContainer.Resolve<IRepository>();
}
```

Manager's methods would look like this:

```
public static MyObject Get(int id)
{
    return _me.Repo.Get(id);
}
```

In my main program (e.g a Console application), I will register my implementation.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = Singleton.UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();
    // The implementation to inject, could change over time
    // to a MSSQL or MySQL, who knows? Hence the DI!
    var myXmlRepo = new XmlRepository("C:\My.xml");
    // Register the instance
    container.RegisterInstance(myXmlRepo);
    container.RegisterInstance<IRepository>(myXmlRepo, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); // Why do I need to register TWICE?
}
```

So, to summarize my question:

1. Is it a bad idea to use a singleton reference (not only to a container, but at all?) in the way shown above?
2. Am I doing the resolving right? Or should I have used BuildUp somewhere? Should I have called Resolve from the startup projects code?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You don't need to register twice, the last line should do if you will resolve by interface. You can also make container create the instance of XmlRepo itself, just pass the parameter for the constructor:
`container.RegisterType<IRepository, XmlRepository>("C:\My.xml", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())` but this will not return you the exact instance

Comment: Yes, I do need to register twice - else it wont resolve it correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770580/resolve-may-fail-depending-on-order-of-registerinstance-and-registertype/5774549#comment21181656_5774549

Comment: Mine works without registering twice but endeed with `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` - not the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`

Comment: Strange - I will have to test this a bit more.

Comment: Edited my answer to privide full example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies should be resolved in cascade down from the top layer classes, not using static or singleton container in constructors.

Check this [link](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-the-static-or-singleton-container).

If your app does not provide any hook into the pipeline to resolve the dependencies (as `Unity.Mvc3` does with controllers) the best aproach is resolve the `Manager` (your top layer class) class through Unity (you must register it first) and let the DI container inject `IRepository`. This alows you to keep the static/singleton container in one place and keep things under control. No other layer in your app should know anything about DI container.

An example of resolving complete dependency graph could be the next piece of code:

```
Public Class ClasificationManagement //application layer service, top layer class
    Implements IClasificationManagement

    Private _servicio As IClasificacionesService //inject domain serice for bussines
    Private _repositorio As IClasificationRepository //inject repository for perisitence

    Public Sub New(ByVal servicio As IClasificacionesService, ByVal repositorio As IClasificationRepository)
        _servicio = servicio
        _repositorio = repositorio
    End Sub

    Public sub SwapDescrition(ByVal clasificationOrigenID As String, ByVal clasificationDestinoID As String) Implements IClasificationManagement. SwapDescrition

        //code using domain services and repositories

    End sub

Public class ClasificacionesService
    implements IClasificacionesService

  private _tracer as ITracer //inject tracer to service domain

  public sub new(tracer as ITracer)
    _tracer =  tracer
  end sub

  //not relevant code using ITracer

End Class
```

With the prorper configuration of Unity in XML or runtime I just need to resolve ClasificationManagement and Unity do the dirty work of resolving all dependecy chain.

```
//resolve manager
    manager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Of IClasificationManager)()
//use manager, all dependencies (bussines service, repositories, tracers) were injected by Unity
    manager.SwapDescrition("123-ABC", "456-DEF")
```

For Unity config I like xml configuration because you can change the dependencies and no compilantion is needed. Just include this function somewhere in the initialization logic of your app.

```
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Unity
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
    Private Sub InitServiceLocator()
        Dim container As IUnityContainer = New UnityContainer()
        container.LoadConfiguration() //read xml config
         //container.RegisterType<Of ...>(...) //config in runtime
        Dim provider = New UnityServiceLocator(container)
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(Function() provider)
    End Sub
```

A XML config should looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

    <alias alias="IClasificationManagement" type="AppPrincipal.IClasificationManagement, AppPrincipal" />
    <alias alias="IClasificationRepository" type="X509ValDAL.IClasificationRepository, X509ValDAL" />
    <alias alias="IClasificacionesService" type="Entidades.IClasificacionesService, Entidades" />
    <alias alias="IUnitOfWork" type="X509ValDAL.IUnitOfWork, X509ValDAL" />
    <alias alias="ObjectContext" type="System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext, System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <alias alias="ClasificationManagement" type="AppPrincipal.ClasificationManagement, AppPrincipal" />
    <alias alias="ClasificationRepository" type="X509ValDAL.ClasificationRepository, X509ValDAL" />
    <alias alias="ClasificacionesService" type="Entidades.ClasificacionesService, Entidades" />
    <alias alias="UnitOfWork" type="X509ValDAL.UnitOfWork, X509ValDAL" />
    <alias alias="X509VALEntities" type="Entidades.X509VALEntities, Entidades" />


    <assembly name="AppPrincipal" />
    <assembly name="X509ValDAL" />
    <assembly name="Entidades" />
    <assembly name="System.Data.Entity" />

    <namespace name="AppPrincipal" />
    <namespace name="X509ValDAL" />
    <namespace name="Entidades" />
    <namespace name="System.Data.Objects" />
    <container>

        <register type="IClasificationManagement" mapTo="ClasificationManagement">
            <constructor>
                <param name="servicio">
                    <dependency/>
                </param>
                <param name="repositorio">
                    <dependency/>
                </param>
            </constructor>
        </register>
    <register type="IClasificationRepository" mapTo="ClasificationRepository">
            <constructor>
                <param name="uow">
                    <dependency/>
                </param>
            </constructor>
        </register>

        <register type="IClasificacionesService" mapTo="ClasificacionesService" />
                 TODO: Inject ITracer

        <register type="ObjectContext" mapTo="X509VALEntities" />

        <register type="IUnitOfWork" mapTo="UnitOfWork" >
            <constructor>
                <param name="context">
                    <dependency />
                </param>
            </constructor>
        </register>     

    </container>
</unity>
```

I hope this example hepls you to understand the phylosophy of DI. Even when I use a static container (ServiceLocator); the container is used just to load top level layer classes to avoid servicelocator antipattern.

Comment: I checked the link, and I see how I am supposed to only have my top layer know about the container - I am not sure of how to "resolve in cascade down" though, would you mind providing an example? :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I got that part, but could you show me where you tell the application to use a specific implementation? Where do you register to your container?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is confusing me even more.. So by using XML, you can inject the members without using a Dependency atrribute? How does it work?

Comment: I think I get it - how much code does it take to configure Unity with code, in the same way you configured it with XML there? +1 for now. :)

Comment: It takes less lisnes of text of course. You already know how to do it as is done in your code. But if you want to create a new implementation of IClasificacionesService you can create a new dll with the implmementation, configure Unity's XML, upload to production the XML and the new dll, restart the app in a couple of seconds and your app is using the new implementation. Awesome!

Comment: Anyway, I think that config in runtime or in XML is not the point of your question. I'm just trying to point you to the right direction of understanding how DI changes your software architecture and how do it in a good way. I hope that the two question you post at the end of your text is aswered.

Comment: Isn't it considered bad practice that the application layer knows about what DAL implementation you are using? It seems to me (despite using an xml file) you are telling the application what implementation you are using.

Comment: The application layer doesn't knows about DAL implementation because IClasificationRepository is a interface and I can change its implementation without touching anytihng in application layer, enough for me. If you are talking about generic repository, well... type "generic repositoy antipattern" in google. Anyway, you know how is programming and software architecture, we can be talking about the pro and cons of different approaches a lot of years without an aggrement. :)

Comment: What I mean is, if you were to be using code instead of a config file, the application project would have dependencies, because it would need to know what implementation to register in the container?

Comment: You're right. The assembly with the code mapping Interfaces to implementations must include non logical flow dependecies. You can save this gap putting that code into an stand allone asssembly and expose (for my example) InitServiceLocator function and Servicelocator to external consumers. This way allows you to keep only one reference to (for example) DependecyInjection.dll in the controllers of your view to resolve application layer classes.

Comment: Please, keep in mind that my example in the answer is just a example and not a complete software architecture that you must follow literally. There are many concerns and issues not taken into account.

Comment: If you want to continue with a discursion about software architecture with dependecy injection, please, send me a e-mail as it is a better way to communicate and reply than StackOverflow comments. If you wish we can work together to define a complete architecture skelleton with Unity's DI.

Comment: Yes, that would be great! How can I email you?